# Ожидание, бесконечный цикл (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  ScreenWidth = screen.width;     
  ScreenHeight = screen.height;     
  if (ScreenWidth < 480){
    jQuery(".wishmod").html(" В отложенное");
    setTimeout("jQuery('ymaps').css('display','none')",5000);
  }

  jQuery(".text_zoom").addClass("hidden");
})
```

Как сделать так, чтоб функция прогонялась каждую секунду, до бесконечности, при том, чтоб это не влияло на работу страницы, ну, чтоб не было загрузки, и торможения, обычный `for`, `while`, не работают

Comment: И не стоит в качестве первого параметра в `setTimeout` передавать строку. Это плохой подход. Передавайте функцию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы функция запускалась через какой то промежуток времени можно использовать [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, можно использовать рекурсивный [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/settimeout):

```js
const interval = 1000;
(function tick(){
 // Your code...
 console.log(performance.now());
 // ... Your code
 setTimeout(tick, interval);
})();
```

Преимущества перед setInterval:

1. чуть проще контролировать выполнение (в случае с setInterval вам надо записать куда-то id и вызывать clearInterval если вы хотите изменить время задержки/прекратить выполнение, в случае с setTimeout вы перед каждым вызовом можете скорректировать задержку следующего выполнения, либо по условию вообще выйти из рекурсии.
2. если ваш код выполняет какие то долгие вычисления (сравнимые по длительности с самим интервалом), то подход с рекурсией и setTimeout избавит вас от положения, когда старые вычисления еще идут, а вы уже начинаете следующий цикл

Недостатки:
 Больше печатать.